# New ram prevents PC from booting up

Tags: boot, memory

I have an AsRock H55M-Pro with a core i3-530, running Windows 7 64-bit.
I have 2x2GB of Crucial RAM running in it at the moment (slots A2, B2).
I purchased 2x4GB sticks of Kingston HyperX ram 2400.

My problem is that when I tried to boot my pc with the new ram installed, it did not boot past the boot screen. My keyboard was not functioning (lights were off), therefore I could not load into the BIOS. The PC did not boot past the boot screen, into Windows.

I've read that the ram should default to a safe setting, so I'm a little confused as to why the new ram is not working. I appreciate that I 'do not need ram at 2400' speeds; however it was on offer.

The ram was installed whilst there was no power to the PC and I have also tried to install the ram into both slots A1,B1 and A2,B2.

Comment: You followed ESD procedures?

Comment: @Ramhound I don't have anti static equipment, but i did try to ground myself via holding my pc case/other metal object

Comment: Holding a loose metal object does nothing to prevent ESD you have to be grounded to (earth) ground to so anything

Comment: @Ramhound, sure it does; touching the chassis ensures that there is no voltage between you and it.  Unless you are rubbing the chips on the ground, then it doesn't matter if there is any potential between the chassis and ground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of RAM needs to suit the PC.  Yours doesn't. Its not only speed that you need to take into account, there are ECC, Buffered or Unbuffered, CAS, number of channels to worry about (in addition to physical characteristics which are probably not at issue here).

In short, the memory is not compatible with your motheboard.

Comment: Would this be because the ram is at a higher voltage than usual? How can I go about checking if the ram is compatible? Thanks for your reply

Comment: I just realised that H55 is not listed in the list of compatible chipsets. Is there a work around?

Comment: The part numbers for each part would be particularly useful in working through the issue - you will probably find there is no workaround - memory generally either works or doesn't.

Comment: No; there is no work around; the memory cannot be used on the motherboard in question

Comment: Thank you both for your help. Hopefully, I can return it